# How do I stop getting emails from GitHub when someone comments on my commit?

Tags: github

I managed to do this on GitHub by unwatching repos, but if I use `git push` then it still sends me emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your email notifications for `pushes` to your repository is on most probably. You can turn off that, for doing this you can do the followings:

1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
2. Under your repository name, click  Settings.
3. Click Notifications.

and check if your notifications is on for this repo, if yes then turn off it.